# Acessando variável PHP dentro JSON

Tags: php, json, api

Eai galera, estou em um projeto em que para o cliente fazer acesso a API precisa ser inserido uma variável PHP dentro do JSON, o exemplo seria esse ao qual estou usando

```
$input = $request->all();

$email = ['email'];

'body' => '{

    "nome":"Guilherme", "cpf":"123456789/77", "email":"$email"
}'
```

Porém, mesmo que eu coloque as chaves {} para especificar a variável (acredito ser o jeito mais comum), não estou conseguindo ter acesso a ela.

Comment: Olá, Guilherme. Poderia alterar a sua pergunta colocando um trecho de código funcional para facilitar o entendimento? a parte do body não possui uma sintaxe válida para o PHP, e, caso alguém tente executar o seu exemplo de código, não terá sucesso.

Answer (score -3):

```
$dados_json = [
    'nome' => 'Guilherme',
    'cpf' => '123456789/77',
    'email' => $email
];

$json = json_encode($dados_json);
```

Isso ajuda?